# How to avoid html5 canvas to be refreshed on page refresh

Tags: html, canvas, page-refresh

In a webpage i have a html5 canvas who takes a lot of time to initialize and once it is ready i would like to avoid refreshing it. Currently on page refresh the canvas is reloaded form scratch introducing a long waiting time.

Is there a way, even a workaround (a "non documented canvas attribute or a save to local storage trick"), to avoid this?

Comment: If it only has to survive across a page refresh you could do `canvas.toBlob(b=>localStorage.mycanvas = URL.createObjectURL(b));` when you've finished drawing it, and `if(localStorage.mycanvas){let img = new Image(); img.onload=e=>ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); img.onerrror=e=>{localStorage.mycanvas=''; defaultInit();} img.src=localStorage.mycanvas; }else{defaultInit()};` **But if it is always the same result, why don't you simply save a png version on your server ?**

Comment: you can use LocalStorage for caching the canvas, and even save half of the canvas on your server so the loading time would be a lot less, and event if you can't find a way to reduce the time you can use setTimeout and setInterval (and other alternatives) instead of for / while loops or even  heavy calculations and add a loading to it. it would take even more time to complete but you would have a nice loading at least.

Comment: thanks a lot. In fact i am using a unity canvas, so the canvas is not just an image, but a complete webgl engine. btw if there were a trick to do it it would have been a great pro, but it seems i need to work it around in another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way that I know of to avoid refreshing the canva as it would go against the basic idea of refreshing the page, but have you considered cacheing the initialised data in the locale or session storage?

Cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage